# How does ghc perform type inference in

Tags: haskell

I working through the Paul Hudaks highly recommended book [Haskell School of Expression](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521644089).
In the 13:th chapter I stumbled across this definition

```
type Time = Float

newtype Behavior a = Beh (Time -> a)
```

The author has declared several instances of the newtype `Behavior`: `Eq`, `Show`, `Num`, `Fractional` and `Floating`, but among these it´s only one function in one of these instance declarations that is bugging me:

```
instance Num a => Num (Behavior a) where
  (+) = lift2 (+)                                   -- This one!
  fromInteger = lift0 . fromInteger

lift0 :: a -> Behavior a
lift0 x = Beh (\t -> x)

lift2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> (Behavior a -> Behavior b -> Behavior c)
lift2 g (Beh a) (Beh b)
   = Beh (\t -> g (a t) (b t))                      -- Or actually this one.

time :: Behavior Time
time = Beh (\t -> t)
```

The author describes, after this, that with these new function declarations we can now write `time + 5` and thus lift the `(+)` operator into the realm of Behavior, or something in that fashion. That sounds all good to me, so I nod and smile as I read along. Suddenly, the author explains that: `(time + 5)` is equivalent to `Beh (\t -> t + 5)`, which sounds totally whacked. He actually even provides this unfolding of the expressions to prove it:

```
time + 5
==> { unfold overloadings for time, (+), and 5 }
(lift2 (+)) (Beh (\t -> t)) (Beh (\t -> 5))
==> { unfold lift2 }
(\ (Beh a) (Beh b) -> Beh (\t -> a t + b t)) (Beh (\t -> t)) (Beh (\t -> 5))
==> { unfold anonymous function }
Beh (\t -> (\t -> t) t + (\t -> 5) t )
==> { unfold two anonymous functions }
Beh (\t -> t + 5)
```

This is more specifically what I´m having trouble understanding. To me the correct statement would be: `time + (Beh 5)` is equivalent to `Beh (\t -> t + 5)`. But when I infer the type in ghci it tells me (of course) that the author is right and that I´m stupid in some formal way. Can someone please explain it to me.

Comment: `Beh 5` would be wrong. It should be `Beh (const 5)`, as `5` is not a function.

Comment: I think your real problem is that you are missing the [`fromInteger`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromInteger) part of the `Num` class - this is where you "wrap" the `5` into a `Behaviour`;)

Comment: The expression `time + 5` is actually equal to `Beh (\ t -> t + (5 t))`.  Look at the `fromInteger` method for `Num (Behaviour a)`.  The crucial point is that integer literals have an implicit `fromInteger`, so when you write 5 it's actually `fromInteger (5::Integer))`.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė That is a good point, but as I explained I type checked the expression and (time + 5) :: Behaviour Time

Comment: @CarstenKönig should I add it so you can explain?

Comment: @augustss Oh I see, now I understand, let me adjust the question.

Comment: @tempestadept just did (kindof) - it's just that you `integer constants` are *overloaded* for each `Num` instance so you can have `5 :: Int`, `5 :: Float` and yes even `5 :: Behaviour a`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(+)` has type `Num a => a -> a -> a`. Here `a` is `Behavior Float`. The literal `5` in your code is converted to `Behavior Float` with `fromInteger`, which should look like `fromInteger n = Beh (\t -> fromInteger n)`.

`Beh 5` wouldn't typecheck since `Beh` wraps a function of type `Float -> a`, not a number.